# Failed opening required JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php

Tags: php, joomla-3.9, helix3

I update my Joomla version from 3.9.13 to 3.9.25 then I received this error:

> Warning: require_once(/home/MYHOST/public_html/MYSITE/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/MYHOST/public_html/MYSITE/templates/MYTEMPLATE/error.php on line 44
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/MYHOST/public_html/MYSITE/libraries/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php' (include_path='.:/opt/cpanel/ea-php73/root/usr/share/pear') in /home/MYHOST/public_html/MYSITE/templates/MYTEMPLATE/error.php on line 44

I searched online and found this advice:

> in MYTEMPLATE **error.php** change this line
>
> ```
> require_once(JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php');
> ```
>
> to this:
>
> ```
> if (!class_exists('JDocumentRendererHead')) {
>     $head = JPATH_LIBRARIES . '/joomla/document/html/renderer/head.php';
>     if (file_exists($head)) {
>         require_once($head);
>     }
> }
> ```

My problem was fixed, but then I got error 404 and this error:

> linkGraylighter is undefined: /home/MYHOST/public_html/MYSITE/templates/MYTEMPLATE/less/presets.less on line 204

I checked this line, but I can't find any code here just some enter...

I delete enter, but I receive error on line 203 and in 203 line you can see just ( } ).

Comment: Welcome to JSE.  Please take our [tour] while you wait for support.

Comment: Please make sure you're using the latest version of thw Helix template. Judging by the fact you had to make that change to the `error.php` file which already exists in latter versions, you must be using an older version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my problem.

For fix this problem :

Go to Helix template > advanced tab >  Compile LESS to CSS = NO